# can't add shop in store.shopware.com - wrong url

Tags: shopware, shopware6

screen from store.shopware.com - wrong url

[image: 1]

I want to add SW shop to store.shopware.com
url shop which I wanto to add is  https://remiza.com.pl/sklep
and I can't because of "The specified domain is invalid" - look at the screen

I try add https://remiza.com.pl/ (there is only a splash page where users can choose WP site and SW shop) https://remiza.com.pl/sw-domain-hash.html and then I could add but problem is that I can't f.e. use support for that - there are no SW shop on https://remiza.com.pl/

How can I add shop which is in subfolder ?

Comment: Why don't you start a subdomain on your end and connect it to your subfolder? For instance, you could create a subdomain called http://store.remiza.com and have that point to your subfolder /sklep/

Answer (score 0):

On the [Shopware Cloud documentation](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/saas/domains) no support for sub folders is mentioned.

It is a bit unclear what you are trying to accomplish. But if you change the IP of remiza.com.pl to the Shopware Cloud IP, you should be able to use this direct domain for the shop.

If you are trying to have another site (for example WordPress) on "/" and your Shopware cloud store on a subfolder, this cannot work out of the box, as the full domain needs to point to the Shopware cloud server. If this is the setup you are looking for, a proxy solution might help - but it would be much easier to accomplish with a subdomain.